# Using Downloaded sqlite3 file

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I'm developing an app that downloads a sqlite3 file from a server and using it anytime later, but I couldn't read its data after it has been downloaded

I use this code to download:

```
myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[myConnection start];
```

I use this code to get data:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [myMutableData appendData:data];
}
```

and I use this code to save the file:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    [myMutableData writeToFile:kPath atomically:YES]
}
```

After saving the file, I try to use it by this code:

```
{
    const char *SQL = [@"SELECT * from table1" UTF8String];
    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    NSString *file = kPath;
    if (sqlite3_open([file UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        sqlite3_exec(database, SQL, myCallback, (__bridge void*)myArray, NULL);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

My Callback function is:

```
static int myCallback(void *context, int count, char **values, char **columns) {
    // "count" is always zero !!

    return SQLITE_OK;
}
```

My problem is: "count" in the callback function is always zero !!

please help me

Comment: You don't provide any useful information to help solve your problem. Better define "couldn't read its data". Could you open the database? What happened when you tried to query the database? Check all return values from the various `sqlite3_xxx` function calls. Get the database error using `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have updated the question and made it more clear.

Comment: After downloading the file, use the iOS file manager functions to materialize the file's size.  Make sure it exists and is not zero length.

Comment: You are trying to open the database file "FILE_NAME.db" from the app's resource bundle. It is impossible to write your downloaded file to the resource bundle. Where do you actually write the downloaded file? Make sure you reference the downloaded file when you open the database.

Comment: I have checked the file and it exists.  the path of the file is: '[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FILE_NAME.db"]'

Comment: Be wary about checking to see if the file exists, because the process of calling `sqlite3_open` will create it as well. I'd (a) reset the simulator and/or delete and reinstall app (b) check the `BOOL` return code of `writeToFile` to make sure it was successful; (c) check the contents to make sure it's the same as server file (i.e. not zero bytes, not a 404 HTML file); (d) if doing HTTP, make sure to use `didReceiveResponse` to check for success/failure; (e) use `sqlite3_open_v2` so it won't create the file for you.

Comment: @iphoner since you are saving the file in the Documents directory, you must open the file in the Documents directory, not the resource bundle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !

My mistake was:
I have updated the database file locally and I forgot to update it in my server
stupid mistake !

Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

1. Your database path should:

   - Should presumably be generated by [`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains);
   - Should be the same in the `connectionDidFinishLoading` as `sqlite3_open`;
   - As a matter of programming style, you might want to use a different variable name than `kPath`, which might suggest it was a constant, whereas it obviously is not.
2. You should check the result of your call to `writeToFile` to make sure it was saved correctly.
3. If running on the simulator, you should inspect the file after the download (manually in the Mac OS Finder, not via your app ... it should be in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/...`) Navigate to the simulator's folder and check out the file that was downloaded. Look at the file size and see if your server values match what was downloaded.
4. One of the more subtle issues is that if your database URL was using a HTTP protocol and was not found, you will not see `didFailWithError` from your `NSURLConnection`, but rather it will blithely downloading the web server's 404 error page from your web server. Make sure the download succeeded by manually inspecting the resulting file.

   If you're using `NSURLConnection` and downloading via HTTP and want to programmatically ensure you didn't get an error, you can use `didReceiveResponse`:

   ```
   - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
   {
       if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]])
       {
           NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (id)response;

           NSInteger statusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];

           if (statusCode == 200)
           {
               // everything is ok
           }
           else if (statusCode >= 400)
           {
               // something went wrong, such as statusCode == 404 or something like that
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. You don't show us the initialization of `myMutableData`. I assume you have done that. You're appending, but if you neglect to initialize that variable, it will carry on without incident, but never save the file:

   ```
   myMutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
   ```
6. The previous problem is insidious, because the process of performing `sqlite3_open` will create the database if it's not there already. I frequently use `sqlite3_open_v2` when opening databases, so I can get an error if the database is not there (or, better, use `NSFileManager` to check for the existence of the file first). You might want to reset your simulator (or delete the app from your device), so that any blank databases that `sqlite3_open` created for you will be removed.
7. Not relevant to your immediate problem, but as an aside, your `NSURLConnection` code is loading the whole database into RAM. If it's not too large you can get away with that, but it's better to stream it to persistent storage to minimize the memory footprint of your download process. This is especially true when running your app on a device (rather than the simulator).

Comment: `kPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"FILE_NAME.db"]` and I have checked the file size after downloading it, and it exists.